# append on element in foreach jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

how to perform this :

```
$(".results tr:not(:first)").each(function(e){
    // somme code
    e.append("<td> display value </td>")
});
```

of course this doesn't work i try whith a seconde value ( f) en doen't work too 
 my whole code is :

```
function affStat(){
    if(localStorage.table == "") return ;
    var table = JSON.parse(localStorage.table);

    $(".results tr:not(:first)").each(function(e, f){
        try{
            //console.log(f.children[1].children[0].title);
            var titre = f.children[1].children[0].title ;
            //console.log(f.children[5].textContent);
            var taille = f.children[5].textContent ;
            var hash = btoa(titre + taille);

            if($.inArray(hash, table)){
             // XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.append("<td> V </td>");
                console.log(hash + "   V");
            }else{
             // XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.append("<td> X </td>");
                console.log(hash + "   X");
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `e` refers to index of element.

The syntax of [**.each()**](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is

```
.each( function(index, Element) )
```

*Change your code to*, Here I have use `this`

```
$(".results tr:not(:first)").each(function(index, element){
    // somme code
    $(this).append("<td> display value </td>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
$(this).append("<td> display value </td>");
//^^^^^----$(this) refers here to the current tr in loop
```

---

Issue with your code:

You have used `e` for the current element which stands for the `index` of that `tr`.
Here `.each( function(e))` if you pass only one arguement in the function then that looks for the index because first arguement as per document is `index`:

```
.each( function(index, Element))
```

---

So i think you can try changing to this too:

```
$(".results tr:not(:first)").each(function(index, e){ // <----pass another arg
   // somme code
   e.append("<td> display value </td>")
});
```